# JavaScript/jQuery: Select specific option trigger file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, triggers

I'm searching for a way to have a HTML select box with arbitrary number of options and have the last option to "Upload a New Item" and trigger a file input element which I've hidden with css (display:none).

My problem is that I just can't get it to work and I've tried various of different functions and methods.

To test it I've tried the same thing with just a regular text link (a href) which works fine.

In addition I've also tried to test the change event on the select to trigger other events which works.
It is like it just won't accept a click trigger of an file input element.

You can see my different tests and approaches here: http://codepen.io/Mestika/pen/rvneK

**edited**
I'm on a Mac running Maverick in a Google Chrome

Cheers

Comment: Worked fine for me on Firefox 28.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to say that I've tested it using Google Chrome.. Thanks for the comment, I'll give it a go in Firefox